# Can I write estimate $\pm$ its standard error?

Tags: confidence-interval, estimation, standard-error, notation

Suppose I have an MLE estimate $\hat{\theta}$ for a parameter $\theta$, and $\hat{\sigma}$ is the sqrt of the inverse of the negative of the Hessian of the log likelihood at $\hat{\theta}$. Can I write $\hat{\theta} \pm \hat{\sigma}$?

In general, if I have an estimate $\hat{\theta}$ for a parameter $\theta$, and an estimate $\hat{\sigma}$ of the standard deviation of $\hat{\theta}$, can I write $\hat{\theta} \pm \hat{\sigma}$? Will others understand what I mean? Is it also what others write?

Comment: under certain regularity conditions MLEs are asymptotically normal.

Answer (score 6):

It's fairly common, but not standard enough that it needs no explanation. $\hat\theta\pm 1.96 \hat\sigma$ is also common—an (approximate perhaps) 95% confidence interval.

Answer (score 4):

I think it depends what you want to convey.

To report the standard error or your estimate you could just write $\hat{\theta} (\hat{\sigma})$. This notation is quite common in the statistical literature, but for the sake of clarity you might mention that the standard error is in parenthesis/brackets the first time you use this notation.

To provide a confidence interval with your estimate you might want to write $\hat{\theta} \pm z_{\alpha/2}\hat{\sigma}$, where $z_{\alpha/2}$ is the quantile of the standard normal distribution and $1-\alpha$ the confidence level of your choice. A common choice is $\alpha = 0.05$ leading to $\hat{\theta} \pm 1.96\hat{\sigma}$.

The second option is a much stronger statement. In addition of providing the standard error of the estimate, it gives a confidence interval relying on the normality of the MLE, which might be too coarse in finite samples: it might include invalid parameter values (e.g., probabilities larger than one), and/or wrongly imply that the confidence interval is symmetric.

Comment: That's a really good point: the nomenclature (symbol-clature?) should be appropriate for the audience. I have never seen the subscript-sigma notation in psychology or biology paper, even it is apparently used frequently in other fields.

Comment: @Matt Krause Indeed, the notation might be field-specific. Please note that in the notation I mentioned the standard error is not a subscript, but rather in parenthesis (e.g., $4.2(0.2)$).

Comment: I've seen that in tables, but I think I would be baffled if I just stumbled across "The average temperature was 4.2(0.2)C" or whatever in a paragraph. All the more reason to explain your notation!

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of parameters that are written as $x \pm y$. Off the top of my head, I have seen people use this format to report:

- mean and standard error:
- mean and standard deviation
- mean and confidence interval
- mean and range/tolerance (particularly on blueprints or design documents)
- median and mean absolute deviation.

All of these are fine, **as long the values are clearly described** Some version of the APA style require explicit labels like "The line's slope was close to unity ($M\pm SE: 1.01 \pm 0.05$). That can be handy, but it can clutter up the text. If you're reporting a lot of values, a simple note ("All data is shown as mean $\pm$ standard errors") can work too.

Obviously, also consider the point you want to make. Standard deviation/MAD/ranges hints at the shape of a distribution, but not about the precision of an estimate. Standard error tells you how precise the estimate is, but does not describe the shape of the distribution.